# What is the point of marking a property as "Value generated on add or update" in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

The Microsoft docs for Entity Framework show that you can mark a property of a type as "Value generated on add or update". So in the situation where I want a `LastUpdated` column to be given the current date when a row is updated, I can mark that property like so:

[image]

But as you can see, it gives a warning that EF isn't going to actually make it happen. Following that link in the warning explicitly tells us that if we want a `Date` column set to the current date whenever a row is updated, *we need to go and create the trigger in the database ourselves* to make it happen.

So what does it **mean**, and what is the **point of** "letting EF know that values are generated for added or updated entities"?

Comment: `Computed` just means database, and not EF, will generate value for this column. Generated value can be anything, it's not like it always "current date" or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, "does not guarantee" bit is indeed a little vague.

But what you do want is for EF to understand that it should include these columns in a Select but not in an Update or Insert.

Answer (score 3):

You are reading it incorrectly. It says

> It *does not guarantee* that EF will...

It doesn't say "EF will not do anything with this". If, for example, you are working on Code First, and you set up the PK to

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

EF will actually set up that column with Identity (on SQL Server).

It also means that EF will not send that value on updates and inserts, since the database is supposed to fill those in.

Remember that EF works with many providers, and it's up to each provider to give that possibility, that's why it's not guaranteed.